# How to access files / directories in disk image that are locked with old permissions?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, virtualization, file-permissions

I just recently upgraded an older desk top Windows computer with a new motherboard, CPU and DIMM memory sticks. The upgrade is meant to still use the same SATA drives a before. Prior to starting the upgrade I used by disk imaging backup software to make a full disk backup of the C: OS Drive that also has 1000's of files I want to keep. The software used for this backup is the O&O DiskImage program.

The backup image was placed on one of the SATA data disks of the system. A copy of the image file was also sent to a NAS box on the same home network for safe keeping.

After the new computer hardware was all installed the old OS disk was wiped clean by using the DISKPART command line utility on a bootable Windows repair/utility DVD. This was done to allow for a completed new install of a new licensed copy of Win10 and eliminate more than a dozen years of disk trash left behind on the old OS setup as it migrated through Win2000/Vista/Win7/Win10.

The new Win10 now comes up nicely and I am ready to bring many if my files back. One of the features of the OS disk backup image on the SATA data disk is that the image can be mounted as a virtual disk drive under Windows using an assigned drive letter.

I was able to copy many files that were located off the root directory level of the mounted virtual disk. I ran into a major hurdle of trying to access files within the \users\Michael folder. When access is attempted the following dialog appears:

[image]

I have tried every thing I could think of to take over ownership of this folder so I can copy out my files. I have even read many web page articles and watched various You-Tube videos on how the this problem is supposed to be overcome. However none of those procedures seem to work with this situation. So I am here seeking help or suggestions to undo the permissions locks in this virtual disk image so I can pull out my files.

Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Comment: Have you tried booting the image via hyper-v (or whatever) and taking ownership from "in there"?  I do not know this to be a solution but it is the first thing that I might try.  Also when I am REALLY stuck, I go to Linux.  I might try mounting the image there to pull the files out.  It manages disk mounting differently and Linux don't give a cr*p about NTFS permissions.

Comment: 1. When you try top change ownership, are you using an Administrator account? 2. When you mount the image, have you made it *writable* so that you can change the permissions./ownership of folders and contents? BTW, Macrium Reflect has features, when mounting a drive image, to make restricted folders accessible to make the image *appear* writable, though nothing is saved to the disk image. Are the O&O images readable by Reflect?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - I have tried to restore the O&O image back to the disk but it would not boot under the new UEFI BIOS on the board. In fact I had tried to boot it with the new UEFI BIOS board even before I wiped the disk clean and went with a new Windows install. The old motherboard had a more legacy type BIOS and I suspect there was some type of incompatibility with the reserved boot manager partition. The old board BIOS was an EVGA adapted BIOS whilst the new one is an ASUS adapted American Megatrends UEFI BIOS. I do not have Linux available.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - 1. The new computer environment is single user install and I should have administrator rights according to what was posted to the screen when I did the new Windows install. Not sure if I have to log in some special way?  2.  As as far as I can tell the O&O mounted image is a read only thing. I suppose I could make a copy and mount that to play and see if it is actually writeable - but I doubt it. I'd have to investigate this "Macrium Reflect" product. I have some hesitancy to have to purchase something.

Comment: What I mean is boot the image WITHIN hyper-v (or whatever) and not try to restore the image back to a disk.  Again, I don't know this to be a solution but this is the first thing I would try to get my files back.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, For individual use, Macrium Reflect Free is available. Whether or not it can read the existing image is another question, though. As for taking ownership of a folder, there are many tools, such as through Explorer (https://www.windowscentral.com/how-take-ownership-files-and-folders-windows-10) or third-party apps: https://www.makeuseof.com/take-ownership-of-windows-files-and-folders-with-these-tools/ . BTW, some Windows folders are owned by TrustedInstaller, not System or Administrator, and are meant to be difficult to access on a running PC.